# static local CCriticalSection doesn't wok correctly

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I found the following code CCriticalSection  doesn't work correctly.

```
foo()
{
    //...
    {
        static CCriticalSection cs; //static local variable
        CSingleLock lock(&cs, TRUE);
        //Critical Section
        non_reentrant_function();
    }
    //...
}
```

But these code is fine:

```
static CCriticalSection cs; //define a global static variable

foo()
{
    //...
    {
        CSingleLock lock(&cs, TRUE);
        //Critical Section
        non_reentrant_function();
    }
    //...
}
```

As we known, static local variable will be initialized only when the function foo  get called for the first time.

What happens to a static local CCriticalSection, if multiple thread call foo?

Comment: "doesn't work" -- see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio before 2015, or other compiler that does not support C++11 "magic static", then construction of static object itself is not properly synchronized.

Even in Visual Studio 2015 / 2017 there's an option to disable "magic static" (`/Zc:threadSafeInit`)